# Trouble with starting a Docker container

Tags: docker, centos, dockerhub

Last night I pushed a basic image of CentOS to Docker Hub and I'm trying to get it to work by pulling it from Docker Hub ([my repository page](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/petergion/centos/general)). Specifically, I'm trying to get "secondCommit" and I ran the image so I have it in my containers. I'm running the container with `docker start <container ID>` and it just shows the container ID in the command prompt but doesn't start it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe lol I literally read it as excited in my head for some reason that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the image using the following command -

```
docker run -ti <image_name>:<tag>
```

Comment: That worked! I don't see -ti as an option in the docker documentation what does it do? I was using -it as a command for the other containers. Also, how do I select this as the answer to this question?